# Time in JHipster

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, jhipster

Is there any way to automatically generate fields of type "time" in the database using JHipster? I'm looking for "time" in SQL (HH:mm:ss), not datetime or date or timestamp. JHipster has Datetime and LocalDate, but not simple "Time". Why?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, most of the database use these other data types (datetime, date and timestamp) to represent time, since these types are enough to handle time information gracefully. The point of displaying something like (HH:mm:ss) looks to me like just a matter of how you want to show the date/time information to the user (in this case, getting rid of the date part).

Answer (score 0):

As of today Jhipster has Instant as a field to map time.